# How to calculate joint probability based on result of two conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have P(Headache|Stress) = 0.88 where Stress is a "necessary" cause.

Again, I have P(Headache|Coffee) = 0.35 where Coffee is also a "necessary" cause.

Now I want to calculate joint effect of Stress and Coffee on Headache which is P(Headache| (Stress and Coffee)). How can I calculate that? What extra information do I need for this?

Thanks in advance.

ISSUE: Based on the answer provided below I calculated another combination,

P(Headache|(High Stress and Lack of Sleep)) where P(Headache | High Stress) = 0.88 and P(Headache | Lack of Sleep) = 0.75, Now I am getting,

P(Headache|(High Stress and Lack of Sleep)) = 1.24

How is this possible? What is wrong here? @Hamed please help.

Comment: I think S and C are independent events in the context. Because having stress does not impact probability of having coffee anyway. 

So, in that case, P(H|S,C) = 0.88*0.35 = 0.308 right? But what is the meaning of this? Does it mean, probability of having a headache is less when both Stress and Coffee are considered together? How is that possible? Can you explain a little? @Hamed

Comment: sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $S\perp C$ we have
\begin{align}
P(H|S,C)&=\frac{P(S,C,H)}{P(S,C)}=\frac{P(S,C|H)P(H)}{P(S,C)}\\
&=\frac{P(S|H)P(C|H)P(H)}{P(S)P(C)}=\frac{P(H|C)P(H|S)}{P(H)}
\end{align}

PS: That (for your special case) is the probability of having headache if a person has stress and drinks coffee. Note that we assume that having stress and drinking coffee are independent events(that might not be true).

Comment: Alright. So now P(H|S,C) = 0.58 as from my data P(H) = 0.53. Can you help me to understand the physical meaning of this? I thought the overall probability for P(H|S,C) will be greater than 0.88. But it is not so, what am I missing here? @Hamed

Comment: I edited my question to describe an issue. However, I think P(H) in the denominator is not necessary. Otherwise the probability becomes greater than 1. @Hamed

Comment: Hi @user79638. P(High Stress) = 0.88 not clear. is that conditional probability? e.g. pr(H|HS)=0.88? or ...

Comment: Oops sorry, my mistake. you are right. Those are conditional probabilities. P(H|HS) = 0.88 and P(H|LoS) = 0.75. P(H) = 0.53. @Hamed

Comment: Hi @user79638 It could be a good question to be asked. please explain that in a new topic.